# django template link to dynamic url

Tags: django, templates, dynamic, hyperlink

I try to make a list from a dictionary, where I also have the name of a view stored (`values.1`). So with every hit of the for loop I can link to the right page. Problem is, I can't figure out how I should fix the `{{ url "view_name" }}`.

My template:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Timers</th>
    </tr>       
    {% for key, values in timers.items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ url values.1 }}">{{ values.0 }}</a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

How can I change the url so it directs to `value.1`?

Sample of timers:
(keep in mind that views names are now still pretty much the same but they wont be on other occasions)

```
OrderedDict([('short job', ['Now', 'short_job']), ('medium job', ['Now', 'medium_job']), ('long job', ['Now', 'long_job']), ('booze', ['Now', 'booze']), ('drugs', ['Now', 'drugs']), ('heist', ['Now', 'heist']),  ('bullet deal', ['Now', 'bullet_deal'])])
```

Comment: Please post a sample value of `timers`.

Comment: Are you having some error?

Comment: Could not parse the remainder: ' values.1' from 'url values.1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`url` is a template tag and not a variable, so changing:

```
{{ url values.1 }}
```

into:

```
{% url values.1 %}
```

should do the trick.